# Upload image with JavaScript from another server via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying (if it's possible) to make an upload of an image stored on another site (not on computer) via JavaScript (jQuery allowed) with an AJAX request.

Lets say that we have the image `http://example.com/a.jpg`. I need to make an AJAX request, submiting this image to `http://test.com/process.php`.

- I can't edit the file `process.php` to accept anything than a *valid uploaded file*.
- Browser support is not important.

Is this even possible ? Because of security issues we canțt dynamicaly populate a file field, so maybe the is another way to send the file without having the user to select the file.

I think I should use `FormData`, not sure.

Comment: I think you are going to hit Same-origin-policy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: as @BogdanBurim pointed out "test.com" won't accept POST requests from another origin.

Comment: @BogdanBurim, Already thought about this. It is not a problem.

Comment: @Tsalikidis, the post request will be done on the `test.com` site. Allow origin is set on `example.com`.

Comment: The only way I can think of right now is to let user select the image, lets say by clicking, this will send a request to the server (the request contains the image path) and the server will make a POST request to test.com .

Comment: What kind of server you use?

Comment: I want the action to be client side, without modifying the PHP. Sergiu has posted already a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// Recieving File.

```
var url  = "http://example.com/a.jpg"
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.onload = function(e) {
    var blobData = oReq.response; // not responseText


    // Sending data.

    var formData = new FormData();


    // JavaScript file-like object
    var blob = new Blob([blobData], { type: "image/jpeg"});

    formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "http://test.com/process.php");
    request.send(formData);
}
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";
oReq.send();
```

Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Wow, so this is possible to do on client side. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Lets say example.com is showing a number of images to user.

- User clicks an image
- A GET request is sent to the server (contains an "image" parameter)
- Server makes a POST request to test.com

So **IF** you code the server in PHP your code should look like this (or something like this):

```
<?php

$image = $_GET['image']; // example.png
$file = dirname(__FILE__).$image; // /var/www/example/assets/img/example.png

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('file' => $file);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.com/process.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);

?>
```